# Loki Promtail dynamic label values extraction from logs - scrap-config

Tags: grafana-loki

The Log entry looks like this

```
2022-05-12 10:32:19,659 - root:loadrequestheaders:33 - INFO: otds=XYZ, domain=XYZ, username=user, origin=10.98.76.67
```

I tried to add the promtail configuration to scrap log entry to get new labels :
Updated ConfigMap - loki-promtail with below content

```
 - job_name: kubernetes-pods-static
      pipeline_stages:
      - match:
          selector: '{container="model"}'
          stages:
          - regex:
              expression: '\.*username=(?P<username>\S+).*origin=(?P<origin>\S+)'
          - labels:
              username:
              origin:
```

I could see loki pods are running successfully with above config map update but I don't see the entries  "username and origin" - in the labels list
Any suggestion on how to add new labels in loki datasource.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ujko.png)